# Unable to use CSS from Angular2 Dart application (CSS shim)

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, angular, dart

I have Angular2 application in Dart (as here  - https://angular.io/docs/dart/latest/quickstart.html) and calling javascript from there (D3.js library)

Problem: css is not loaded for svg circle

app_root.dart:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'root',
  templateUrl: 'app_root.html',
  styleUrls: const ['app_root.css'],
)
class RootComp {
 Future showCircle() async {
    injectScript('http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js');

    final d3 = await js.context['d3'];
    var svg = d3['select']('root')
    ['append']('svg')
    ['attr']('width', 100)
    ['attr']('height', 100);

    svg['append']("circle")
    ['attr']("class", "circlemy")
    ['attr']("r", 40)
    ['attr']("cx", 50)
    ['attr']("cy", 50);
    }
}
```

app_root.html:

```
<div class="host-root">Pages with circles</div>
```

app_root.css:

```
.host-root {
  color: purple;
}
.circlemy {
  fill: blue;
}
```

Since I use Angular2 components, my css file is transformed to following after build:

```
.host-root[_ngcontent-qxh-1] {
  color: purple;
}
.circlemy[_ngcontent-qxh-1] {
  fill: none;
}
```

and resulted html contains following code:

```
<div ng-app="">
<root _nghost-qxh-1="">
    <div _ngcontent-qxh-1="" class="host-root">Page with circles</div>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
    <circle class="circlemy" r="40" cx="50" cy="50"></circle></svg>
</root></div>
```

I read that adding those `_ngcontent-qxh-1` tags in Angular2 is called shiming. In https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/wiki/CSS-Shim  I read that "Dynamically-created DOM will not be shimmed"

Is there a way I can use css for my svg circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the rewriting of the styles and addition of the attributes is to simulate style encapsulation similar to shadow DOM.

Angular doesn't add these attributes to HTML that is added dynamically.

As workaround this should work:

```
:host >>> .host-root {
  color: purple;
}
:host >>> .circlemy {
  fill: blue;
}
```

This way the selector is treated like to everything within `<root>` (template or children) that matches `.host-root` the styles will be applied.

Comment: now css became like '[_nghost-ffi-1]   .circlemy {..}', so host-root is ok as before, circle is not displayed at all (because there is some exception, but I dont see javascript exception, only dart, but that's another problem)

Comment: Did you inspect the DOM? Is the `<circle>` added where you expect it? Did it get the `fill: blue`? style applied? Why don't you see JS exception? You could try without `>>>` (just a space)

Comment: your original answer was correct (both >>> and " " work), I looked on wrong page when was checking that, silly mistake. Thanks a lot for such quick answer!

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out :)